# How to match all whitespaces(if any) before words in group using C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match all whitespaces (if any) before words.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"(\d+);([\d\.]+);([\d\.]+);([\w-\(\)\.,\/]+);(\d+);(\d+);([\d,]+);(\d+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

The above regex is working for Example-1 but not for Example-2.
Where do I need to change the regex for Example-2?

```
Example-1:
44;52.93; 8.24;GROSSENKNETEN;201902;28;408.7;28;509.86
71;48.22; 8.98;ALBSTADT-BADKAP;201902;28;475.3;28;-999.9
73;48.62;13.05;ALDERSBACH-KRIESTORF;201902;28;519.8;28;561.76
```

```
Example-2:
00044;52.93; 8.24;            GROSSENKNETEN;201907;31; 53.4;9; 28.6
00071;48.22; 8.98;          ALBSTADT-BADKAP;201907;31; 49.0;8;-999.9
00073;48.62;13.05;     ALDERSBACH-KRIESTORF;201907;31;  0.0;0; 15.7
```

Comment: Why not just split your input by `;`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev in my context I can't split, only need to match.

Comment: Well, if you insist on it, try `@"(?m)^(\d+);\s*([\d.]+);\s*([\d.]+);\s*([\w-().,\/]+);\s*(\d+);\s*(\d+);\s*([\d.]+);\s*(\d+);\s*([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)\r?$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks a lot. It works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a normal access to full C# functionality, just read a file line by line and split with `;` to get all the fields.

If you are using a .NET regex based tool and need to extract specific data from lines of text, you may use

```
(?m)^(\d+);\s*([\d.]+);\s*([\d.]+);\s*([\w-().,\/]+);\s*(\d+);\s*(\d+);\s*([\d.]+);\s*(\d+);\s*([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)\r?$
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%5Cd%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5B%5Cw-%28%29.%2C%5C%2F%5D%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5B%5Cd.%5D%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5Cd%2B%29%3B%5Cs*%28%5B-%2B%5D%3F%5Cd*%5C.%3F%5Cd%2B%29%5Cr%3F%24&i=44%3B52.93%3B%208.24%3BGROSSENKNETEN%3B201902%3B28%3B408.7%3B28%3B509.86%0D%0A71%3B48.22%3B%208.98%3BALBSTADT-BADKAP%3B201902%3B28%3B475.3%3B28%3B-999.9%0D%0A73%3B48.62%3B13.05%3BALDERSBACH-KRIESTORF%3B201902%3B28%3B519.8%3B28%3B561.76%0D%0A%0D%0A00044%3B52.93%3B%208.24%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROSSENKNETEN%3B201907%3B31%3B%2053.4%3B9%3B%2028.6%0D%0A00071%3B48.22%3B%208.98%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ALBSTADT-BADKAP%3B201907%3B31%3B%2049.0%3B8%3B-999.9%0D%0A00073%3B48.62%3B13.05%3B%20%20%20%20%20ALDERSBACH-KRIESTORF%3B201907%3B31%3B%20%200.0%3B0%3B%2015.7)

In a multiline mode, the `$` in .NET regex does not match before a CR, that is why there is a `\r?`.

**Pattern details**

- `(?m)` - multiline mode on
- `^` - start of a line
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `;` - a semi-colon
- **`\s*` - 0+ whitespaces**
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 2: 1+ digits or dots
- `;\s*([\d.]+);\s*` - `;`, 0+ whitespaces, Group 3: 1+ digits/dots, `;`, 0+ whitespaces
- `([\w-().,/]+)` - Group 4: 1+ word, `-`, `(`, `)`, `.`, `,`, `/` chars
- `;\s*(\d+);\s*(\d+);\s*` - `;`, 0+ whitespaces, Group 5: 1+ digits, `;`, 0+ whitespaces, Group 6: 1+ digits, `;`, 0+ whitespaces
- `([\d.]+)` - Group 7: 1+ digits/dots
- `;\s*(\d+)` - `;`, 0+ whitespaces, Group 8: 1+ digits
- `;\s*` - `;` and 0+ whitespaces
- **`([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)` - Group 9: `-` or `+` optionally,  then 0+ digits, an optional `.`, 1+ digits**
- **`\r?$` - an optional CR char and the end of the line.**